# Is it possible to avoid the question at softwarechoice during installation?

Tags: installation, 13.04, preseed, alternate

I remastered your Lubuntu-Alternate-Iso, added own packages an a new preseed-file which works fine and is exactly what i was searching for.

There is one problem left, where i found no help using google:

Is it possible to avoid the question at softwarechoice (`openssh-server`, `lubuntu-desktop`, etc.) perhaps in preseed and just install `lubuntu-minimal` without any further question?

Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help

Edit: Sorry, but now I saw, that `lubuntu-minimal` is installing a desktop. Is it possible to install a text-base-lubuntu-alternate without X?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution in preseed:

```
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect minimal
tasksel tasksel/skip-tasks multiselect lubuntu-desktop xorg
```

This does what i want - minimal installation without X. I don't know which line is necessary. Perhaps both are.